# Exclude weekends from calculated-field date using expression-builder MS Access

Tags: ms-access, expression, calculated-field, weekend

i have two fields in my access db table. One contains dates [D] and the other contains numbers [N]. I have created a calculated field that stores ( [D] - [N] ) dates. 
my problem is that i would like to exclude weekends from the dates stored in the calculated field and cant seem to find how to do this from expression builder... is there a way to this? or is there any other way?

thanks

Comment: How are you storing the dates in the calculated field ?

Comment: @RichardSpencer i am using an expression builder... so it kind of stores the results automatically

Comment: Is this on a form or within the table ? If so post what you have and I may have a way to do it.

Comment: @RichardSpencer doing this from the table. I selected the field tab... scolled down to calculated field and selected that. The expression builder comes up automatically and then i selected the two tables i wanted to subtract and hit enter. the table and values are then created automatically

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the [d] column contains a date and [n] is a number of days then a calculated column may look something like :-

```
=IIf(Weekday(DateAdd("d",[n]*-1,[d])) In (7,1),"",DateAdd("d",[n]*-1,[d]))
```

Notes :

- (7,1) on my system Saturday is 7 and Sunday is 1 - this can be
  changed by altering the DateAdd function
- You may wish to replace the
  "" with NULL
- I have assumed [n] is a positive number so using the *-1 to go backwords in days.

Comment: I used the code provided (replacing [n] with my days number and [d] with the target date) and i got an error message saying the expressin can not be used on a calculated field.

Comment: and the should the d in inverted comma's ((Weekday(DateAdd("d"...)be replaced by an actual date?

Comment: "d" ( first argument ) of dateadd tells dateadd that you wish to work in days rather than "y" years or "m" months.